# Initialize only variable once, while function calls itself multiple times

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This function calls itself multiple times - finding a child of a game object and passing that object into itself again.

I want to return a list of game objects that were found while traversing. I can't initialize a list in a function itself because I need to initialize it only once. When calling it multiple times it will re-initialize.

Any idea on how to fetch a list of fetched objects?

```
public static List<GameObject> FindAllGameObjectsInGameObject<T>(GameObject gameObjectToTraverse)
    {
        List<GameObject> list;
        
        

        foreach (Transform child in gameObjectToTraverse.transform)
        {
            if (list == null)
            {
                list = new List<GameObject>();
            }
            list.Add(child.gameObject);
            FindAllGameObjectsInGameObject<T>(child.gameObject);
        }
       

    }
```

Comment: Pass the list in as a parameter

Comment: Avoid recursion. Instead, use a `Stack` instance, insert your first game object in it and then loop for as long as your stack contains at least an element. In the loop, pop the element from the stack, do your stuff and add each of its children in the same stack. Much, much more efficient and elegant.

Comment: Pass the list in as a parameter into the recursive function. Every time you push into a new stack, it sets that instance's list to null

Comment: The answer already given is better for your case, but generally you can do this by having each recursive call return its own list and use `List.AddRange` to add the returned list of each call to the list being built one level higher.  `SelectMany` can also be used to flatten all the returned lists into one list.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian note that it is way better to use only one list and add elements in the first place than creating multiple collections you are going to throw away almost immediately anyway. This creates a lot of waste for the GC and might end up pretty slow, especially when using it repeatedly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing the recursion yourself at all why not simply use [`GameObject.GetComponentsInChildren`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentsInChildren.html)

> Returns all components of Type type in the GameObject or any of its children.
>
> Unity searches for components recursively on child GameObjects. This means that it also includes all the child GameObjects of the target GameObject, and all subsequent child GameObjects.

and do e.g.

```
using System.Linq;
```

and then

```
public static List<GameObject> FindAllGameObjectsInGameObject(GameObject gameObjectToTraverse)
{
    // This already gives you ALL transform components anywhere nested 
    // under the given object including inactive and disabled ones
    // INCLUDING the given object itself
    var allChildTransforms = gameObjectToTraverse.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>(true);
    // This uses Linq to rather get all the according GameObjects 
    // See https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select
    var allChildGameObjects = allChildTransforms.Select(t => t.gameObject);
    // Optional if you don't want to return the original given object itself
    // See https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where
    var onlyChildGameObjects = allChildGameObjects.Where(c => c!= gameObjectToTraverse);

    return onlyChildGameObjects.ToList();
}
```

and forget about recursion since Unity already does it for you ;)

---

Then actually what is the generic parameter `T` for? You probably might want to use it in the first call

```
var allChildComponents = gameObjectToTraverse.GetComponentsInChildren<T>(true);
```

in order to rather get only objects having a component of type `T` attached.

---

Just for actually answering on your attempt: You could use an [optional parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments) like

```
public static List<GameObject> FindAllGameObjectsInGameObject(GameObject gameObjectToTraverse, List<GameObject> list = new List<GameObject>())
{     
    foreach (Transform child in gameObjectToTraverse.transform)
    {
        list.Add(child.gameObject);
        FindAllGameObjectsInGameObject(child.gameObject, list);
    }
}
```

So the first time you call it you just do

```
var objs = FindAllGameObjectsInGameObject(objectToTraverse);
```

in that case a new list is automatically created as second parameter. Then it is passed on internally in the recursive calls.

Or you could just obfuscate it a bit and simply split those two:

```
public static List<GameObject> FindAllGameObjectsInGameObject(GameObject gameObjectToTraverse)
{
    return FindAllGameObjectsInGameObjectInternal(objectToTraverse, new List<GameObject>());
}

private static List<GameObject> FindAllGameObjectsInGameObjectInternal(GameObject gameObjectToTraverse, List<GameObject> list)
{     
    foreach (Transform child in gameObjectToTraverse.transform)
    {
        list.Add(child.gameObject);
        FindAllGameObjectsInGameObjectInternal(child.gameObject, list);
    }
}
```

However, with the optional parameter solution you give the developer the chance to reuse an already existing list instead of creating a new one every time ;)

Comment: That's the most valuable answer I've ever received. +1 for including inactive objects (didn't know about that either) and +1 for not including the original object (you really saw ahead of potential problems i could face. +1 for that also). 

Thanks again for your answer @derHugo and keep up the good work. I see you a lot on this side of stackoverflow :D